# Find a specific line of code in wordpress themes

Tags: wordpress, location, line, firebug

i have a WordPress theme , there is a line that i wanna change in it , but i just can't find it in all of the pages, i tried inspecting it with firebug and i can see the code line in firebug but i don't know where is that line written in the files, is there is anyway to know where is the physical location of that line in the files, and it's stored on my local host so i can access the server, please help 
Thank you very much

Comment: Search that div with that particular class or id. Or search for a parent div.

Comment: Open wp theme in editor(notepad++) and search in all files for specific div id or class

Comment: I don't know , i think firebug shows the generated html code , but not where it was generated from , is there anyway to know that ...?

Comment: Exactly, dev tools like Firebug work on the client side, so they can't tell you what script on the server generated it. They can just tell you the URL that generated the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the files on your computer, you can use a program like Notepad++ on Windows or TextWrangler on Mac to search for that specific phrase in multiple files.

Search > Find in Files in Notepad++
Search > Multi-File Search in TextWrangler

Then select the folder or folder group and search for your specific term.

Comment: They are over 3500 files is there another way to pin point the location of that line ?

Comment: It will tell you in the program you use where exactly the line is, in which file and on which line. That's why I suggested those two programs.